# What does "tumour budding" mean?

Tags: cancer, terminology

*tumour budding, lymphocytic infiltration and resection margins are established factors that influence the outcome of colorectal cancer* (1)

In this context what does "tumour budding" mean?

Reference

(1) A. Bolocan, D. Ion, D.N. Ciocan, D.N Paduraru. *Chirurgia* (2012) 107:555-563. Introduction/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tumor ‘budding’ is loosely defined as the presence of individual cells and small clusters of tumor cells at the invasive front of carcinomas. A study of the measure of budding can give an insight into how fast the disease might propogate.

[Reference](http://www.nature.com/modpathol/journal/v25/n10/full/modpathol201294a.html)